# Sound not working in Android emulator on MacOS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

Android studio's emulator audio not working i'm on MacOS Big Sur, I tried re-installing Android Studio but it didn't work neither. It works fine on Windows when using Bootcamp and I tried using NOXPlayer and it works as well but I really need the Android SDK Emulator for an app that I'm building. I'm not sure if I missed to give it permission or so but I re-installed it entirely and it still wouldn't work

Answer (score 3):

Closing the emulator >
Going to Device Manager >
and doing a `cold boot now` >
Restarted the emulator and I was able to hear the sounds on the emulator via my mac speaker.
Confirmed in M1 Mac.
Emulator: Pixel 5 Api 33. No modifications done.

Answer (score 1):

Audio on the emulator of my Big Sur Mac works for me. By any chance is the volume on your emulator turned completely down? Also, have you tested alternative sources of sound, such a YouTube video playing in the Chrome app to see if those work?

No additional permission needed to play sound.

Are you using an M1-based Mac? If so, make sure you've upgraded to the latest emulator version (v30.5.6) which I heard fixed a number of issues on M1 Macs.

In the past, I've experience janky emulator issues that defied all explanation... and when I've used the AVD Manager to delete them and re-create a new one, they magically go away. When you say that you uninstalled Android Studio, I wonder if it leaves the emulator image and doesn't remove that? Within the AVD Manager, if you right click on the emulator instance, you can 'Show on Disk' and 'Delete'.

Finally, open System Preferences within macOS and then Sound. Then, click on the Sound Effects tab and set the 'Play sound effects through' to the device that you want to hear the audio. Also, review the Output tab and change the audio output to the source that you desire.

Hopefully that gives you some ideas.

Comment: I have checked the emulator's volume it's on the maximum. And yes I tested with youtube as well and I'm not using M1 based mac. I deleted it completely including the emulators as well

Comment: I just found out that the audio doesn't play through my headset but it works fine on the speakers, any reason on why that happens or how to fix it?

Comment: @effydev I updated the answer to include information on reviewing the macOS System Preferences Sound dialogs.

Comment: I tried what you said already, i've set my output to my headset and sound effects through headset it still wouldn't work. Funny enough I'm setting my output to my macbook speakers then switching back to my headset and the audio simulator still plays audio through my speakers. At least I got some sound I can work with now I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to switch the audio output to the Internal Speakers (then re-start the app). I use a Studio Display with the MacBook in clamshell mode, I had to open it and default to the internal speakers. Quite annoying but at least it works for now.